# Как правильно составить формулу?

Tags: python, python-3.x, формулы, вычислительная-геометрия

В общем, я недавно уже задавал вопрос по поводу программы с циклом и расчета выгодности кредитования. Сильно поменялись условия и реализовывать это надо аля рейтинг в отеле.

Изначальный код выглядел вот так:

```
    # Качество/сервис высокие
def f_good(x):
    if x <= 4:
        return 0
    elif x > 4:
        return 1 - (10 - float (x)) / 6


# Качество/сервис низкие
def f_bad(x):
    if x >= 6:
        return 0
    elif x < 6:
        return 1 - (abs (0 - float (x))) / 6


# Качество/сервис средние
def f_average(x):
    if x <= 2.5 or x >= 7.5:
        return 0
    elif 2.5 < x and x < 7.5:
        return 1 - (float (abs (5 - x)) / 2.5)


# Чаевые  низкие
def t_low(x):
    if x >= 10:
        return 0
    elif x < 10:
        return 1 - (float (x) / 10)


# Чаевые высокие
def t_high(x):
    if x <= 10:
        return 0
    elif x > 10:
        return (float (x) / 10) - 1


# Чаевые средние
def t_average(x):
    if x <= 5 or x >= 15:
        return 0
    elif (5 < x) and (x < 15):
        return 1 - (float (abs (10 - x)) / 5.0)


qf = float (input ("Оцените качество еды (1-10): "))
qs = float (input ("Оцените качество сервиса (1-10): "))

high_score = min (f_good (qf), f_good (qs))
low_score = max (f_bad (qf), f_bad (qs))
average_score = f_average (qs)

print ("Высокие: %.2f, Низкие: %.2f, Средние: %.2f" % (high_score, average_score, low_score))

tip_out = 0
tip_max = 20

degree = max (min (t_low (tip_max), low_score), min (t_average (tip_max), average_score),
              min (t_high (tip_max), high_score))

tip_out += tip_max * degree
print ("Размер чаевых составит: %.2f процентов" % tip_out)
```

Я перерабатывал код для кредитов, но в конце концов запутался с формулами, где функции def f_good и так далее. Я совершенно не понимаю логику 1 - (10 - float (x)) / 6 - слишком много математики и слишком далеко от реальности для меня.

В общем, код мой превратился в это:

```
def h_price(x):
    if x <= 100:
        return 0
    elif x > 100:
        return 1 - (10 - float (x)) / 6


def m_price(x):
    if x <= 150 or x >= 250:
        return 0
    elif 150 < x < 250:
        return 1 - (float (abs (5 - x)) / 2.5)


def l_price(x):
    if x >= 300:
        return 0
    elif x < 300:
        return 1 - (abs (0 - float (x))) / 6


money = input ('Сумма денег: ')
money = int (money)

percent = input ('Процент кредита: ')
percent = int (percent)

years = input ('Насколько лет берется кредит: ')
years = float (years)

percent1 = percent / 100
month_pay = (money * percent1 * (1 + percent1) ** years) / (12 * ((1 + percent1) ** years - 1))
print ('Месячный платеж: %.f' % month_pay)

t_sum = month_pay * years * 12
credit_sum = '%.f%%' % ((t_sum / money) * 100)
print ('Сумма за весь период: %.f' % t_sum)
print ('Это составит', credit_sum, 'от первоначальной суммы')

high_score = min (h_price (money), h_price (percent), h_price (years))
low_score = max (l_price (money), l_price (percent), l_price (years))
average_score = m_price (money)

print ("Высокие: %.2f, Низкие: %.2f, Средние: %.2f" % (high_score, average_score, low_score))
```

Я, в принципе, понимаю как и что работает, кроме формул. Формулы меня просто на лопатки положили, очень хочется разобраться, но боюсь, я только сильнее на этом этапе запутаюсь уже.

Может ли кто-то помочь с формулой расчета для h_price, m_price и l_price? Нужно, как я понимаю, отобразить, насколько близок параметр к условию, что-то с нечетными множествами связанное.

Конечная задача для меня такая: если ввести во второй программе 10000 10 10, то формулы позволяют получить ответ Высокие: 0.00, Низкие: 0.00, Средние: 2.67 и строчка "Это составит 163% от первоначальной суммы". Я хочу реализовать тоже самое для шага от 100% до 300%, где 300% - максимум, а 100%, минимум, но не понимаю числа для этого.

Comment: Вопрос не забывайте задавать.

Comment: `Как правильно составить формулу?` - чего?

Comment: Поправился, вставил в конце вопрос. В плане, формула по типу return 1 - (float (abs (5 - x)) / 2.5) , я просто не понимаю, как это реализовать на других условиях.

Comment: Не надо формул, напишите по русский. Например: Как правильно запрограммировать  формулу рассчета месячного дифференцированного платежа?

Comment: Проблема в том, что я не знаю, как это называется. Это не про платежи точно. Тут суть в отображении. В первой приведенной программе выводится такие данные: "Оцените качество еды (1-10): 2
Оцените качество сервиса (1-10): 2
Высокие: 0.00, Низкие: 0.67, Средние: 0.00"

Comment: Я хочу такой же вывод сделать для расчета кредитования, но не понимаю как, потому что для этого нужна формула оптимизированная именно для этого, а как ее сделать, я не понимаю.

Comment: Сложно дать ответ на вопрос, который даже сам автор не может толком понять и объяснить.

Comment: Пытаюсь изо всех сил объяснить. Что именно непонятно? Самая главная проблема для меня, это блоки с комментариями в первой примере кода, где указаны "Качество/сервис" и тому подобные. Я попросту не понимаю формулу в return. А надо аналогично сделать для второго примера с кодом. Насколько я понимаю, это какая-то подвид нечеткой логики и нечетких множеств, если это может помочь.

Comment: Один из ответом помог сформулировать несколько проблему.  Если ввести во второй программе 10000 10 10, то эти формулы позволяют получить ответ Высокие: 0.00, Низкие: 0.00, Средние: 2.67 и строчка "Это составит 163% от первоначальной суммы". Я хочу реализовать тоже самое для шага от 100% до 300%, где 300% - максимум, а 100%, минимум, но не понимаю числа для этого. Может это поможет?

Answer (score 0):

В общем, разобрался я вроде со всем этим, оказалось, я в принципе неправильно делал все. Оказалось, что условия тут такие:

1. Заемщик оценивается по двум параметрам: Величина дохода (высокий, средний, низкий) (0-10) и Качество кредитной истории (высокий, средний, низкий)(0-10)
2. Одобрение суммы кредита (Высокая, средняя, низкая)(0-500000)

Задача по параметрам заемщика определить сумму кредита (0-500000)

А оптимизированный первый код тут выглядит вот так:

```
# Величина дохода высокие
def h_income(x):
    if x <= 4:
        return 0
    elif x > 4:
        return 1 - (10 - float (x)) / 6


# Величина дохода низкие
def l_income(x):
    if x >= 6:
        return 0
    elif x < 6:
        return 1 - (abs (0 - float (x))) / 6


# Величина дохода средние
def m_income(x):
    if x <= 2.5 or x >= 7.5:
        return 0
    elif 2.5 < x and x < 7.5:
        return 1 - (float (abs (5 - x)) / 2.5)


# Качество кредитной истории  низкие
def l_c_history(x):
    if x >= 10:
        return 0
    elif x < 10:
        return 1 - (float (x) / 10)


# Качество кредитной истории высокие
def h_c_history(x):
    if x <= 10:
        return 0
    elif x > 10:
        return (float (x) / 10) - 1


# Качество кредитной истории средние
def m_c_history(x):
    if x <= 5 or x >= 15:
        return 0
    elif (5 < x) and (x < 15):
        return 1 - (float (abs (10 - x)) / 5.0)


iq = float (input ("Оцените величину дохода (1-10): "))
ch = float (input ("Оцените качество кредитной истории (1-10): "))

high_score = min (h_income (iq), h_income (ch))
low_score = max (l_income (iq), l_income (ch))
average_score = m_income (ch)

print ("Высокие: %.2f, Низкие: %.2f, Средние: %.2f" % (high_score, average_score, low_score))

approval_out = 0
approval_max = 500000

degree = max (min (l_c_history (approval_max), low_score), min (m_c_history (approval_max), average_score),
              min (h_c_history (approval_max), high_score))

approval_out += approval_max * degree
print ("Одобренная сумма кредита:", int(approval_out))
```

Я даже разобрался, как это все называется: экспертная система! В общем, спасибо всем, кто пытался помочь, может пригодится потом кому.

Answer (score -2):

```
1 - (10 - float (x)) / 6
```

Вы работаете на Питон 3, потому не вообще *не нужно* применять `float()`.
Просто это то-же самое как

```
1 - (10 - x) / 6
```

---

Объяснение:

В многих **других** языках программирования (включая Питон 2) выражение

```
9 / 5
```

вычисляется как `1`, потому что *обе числа целые*, и так применяется *целочисленное деление*.

Когда вы хотите **в этих языках** получить результат `1.8`, то хоть бы один операнд должен быть записан как не-целое число (float). Например так:

```
9. / 5   или   9.0 / 5    или    9 / 5.    или    9 / float(5)   и т.д.
```

---

**Но в Питоне 3 вещи по друхому:**

`9 / 5` будет всегда `1.8`,

пока для *целочисленного деления* - другой оператор (`//`):

`9 // 5` (с результатом `1`).

Comment: Вопрос вроде был "что значит эта формула?", а не "можно ли убрать float отсюда?".

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь, по крайней мере, попроще считывать эти формулы. А можете помочь с пониманием значений? Например, если ввести во второй программе 10000 10 10, то эти формулы позволяют получить ответ Высокие: 0.00, Низкие: 0.00, Средние: 2.67 и строчка "Это составит 163% от первоначальной суммы". Я хочу реализовать тоже самое для шага от 100% до 300%, где 300% - максимум, а 100%, минимум, но не понимаю числа для этого.